# Text replacement from a string in php

Tags: php, arrays, regex, string, replace

How do I replace the square bracket and its contents in php.
For example I would like to output something like

```
// 'Hello World Today Hello Everybody Anybody'
```

when I `echo $txt`.

```
$txt = 'Hello World [this-echo] Hello Everybody [nobody]';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a simple search and replace for your defined markers.

```
$text = 'Hello World [this-echo] Hello Everybody [nobody]';
$markers=array('[this-echo]','[nobody]');
$replacements=array('Today','Anybody');
$text= str_replace($markers,$replacements,$text);
```

**Output**

```
Hello World Today Hello Everybody Anybody
```

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/383571)**

Comment: But how do I do this dynamically. When I don't know what are the characters used in this brackets [ ]. Thanks for the above answer @Hanky.

Comment: If you don't know what to replace and what to replace with then how will you replace? What will you replace those markers with? If it has to be 1 fixed dummy replacement for all then you can use regexes

Answer (score -1):

When the content of the brackets is not defined somewhere you can get them with preg_match_all:

```
$string = 'This is a [test]';
preg_match_all('/\[([^\]*]+?)\]/', $string, $matches);
```

The regex will match everything between the opening bracket and the closing bracket and put the results in the matches array.

The matches array for the example:

```
Array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "[test]"
  }
  [1]=>
  Array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "test"
  }
}
```

Now you can replace [test] with something you want and have the content between the brackets available.

Answer (score -1):

Doing it by Regex is one way to achieve your text replacement:

```
$txt = 'Hello World [this-echo] Hello Everybody [nobody]';
$replaced_text = preg_replace('/(\\[[^\\]]*\\])/i', '<TEXTTOREPLACE>', $txt);
echo $replaced_text;
```

**Explanation of the regular expression (/regex/options):**

With:

```
/(\[[^\]]*\])/i
```

you are matching everything from [, all chars except ] to the closing ] ignoring the case with the i at the end of the pattern.

**Ignoring the case (uppercase, lowercase):**

```
/regex/i
```